# Proxy To Backend Service

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I need to proxy an api request of the form `api.myserver.com/service/v1/pricing` to the right backend service.

I configured nginx in this way:

```
location /service/v1 {
         proxy_pass https://service-v1-pool/;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
         proxy_ssl_server_name on;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Connection "";
  }

upstream service-v1-pool {
             least_conn;
             keepalive 32;
             server 192.168.1.10:8000;
}
```

And I setup a basic server at that private address.

The problem is that if I make a request to `api.myserver.com/service/v1/pricing`, the server sees a request `GET //pricing` which fires a `404 Not Found`. The right request should be `GET /pricing`.
Thre is something I'm missing in NGINX?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed the part about URI transformation

https://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass

> A request URI is passed to the server as follows:
>
> - If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, **the part** of a normalized request URI **matching the location is replaced** by a URI specified in the directive

In you case URI is `/service/v1/pricing`, matching part is `/service/v1` and it's replaced with `/` thus you've got `//pricing`.

Just add a trailing slash to `location` and you'll get it right.

```
location /service/v1/ {
    proxy_pass https://service-v1-pool/;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use regexp in the location block:

```
location ~ ^/service/v1/(.*)$ {
         proxy_pass https://service-v1-pool/$1;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
         proxy_ssl_server_name on;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Connection "";
  }
```

or simpler, as suggested in the comment:

```
location /service/v1/ {
    proxy_pass https://service-v1-pool/;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Actually there is much simpler way: just add trailing slash to `location /service/v1/ {...`